# How can I measure the "distance" between two CDFs?

Tags: r

I have a collection of data with interesting numeric numbers that represent the objects.

The data also has CDFs as an attribute.

```
"X"    "Y"    "CDF_Z"
10     31     (piece-wise continuous function)
18     41     ...
...
```

Now, I want to cluster the data using K-means clustering algorithm.
I can use Euclidean distance for "X" and "Y", but I don't know how to measure the distance between two CDFs.

Does any one have an idea on this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Kolmogrov-Smirnof test 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

There is a funtion in R for the same https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html

Answer (score 0):

The authors here http://eliassi.org/papers/henderson-sac15.pdf (EP-MEANS: An Efficient Nonparametric Clustering of
Empirical Probability Distributions) show that taking the KS test statistic is not such a good idea since:

> "KS does not take into account distances in the underlying space of
>   values. For example, any two distributions which have all their mass
>   at a single point will have KS statistic of 1 (if the points are
>   distinct), regardless of how far apart the distributions are. Consider
>   three distributions, each with all its mass at values 0, 1, and 100
>   respectively. KS considers the clustering ((1,2),(3)) equally good as
>   the clustering ((1),(2,3)), although the former is intuitively better"

They propose using the whole area between the curves (also known as Earth Mover's Distance) as a distance metric and show advantages of their approach.

Comment: An example of an application of what Ludecan just showed is here: http://www.noamlupu.com/EMD.pdf. There is a very clear empirical explanation (although directed to a specific field - Political Science). Might be useful for those that are not familiar with the maths involved (like myself). There are also R codes to run it.